# vim syntax highlight limited to 3000 chars

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

How do I allow vim to work its syntax highlight on lines longer than 3000 characters?

I am having to write tests for a system and the input for the tests are a mess of encapsulated formats.

My tests must have hardcoded inputs that are a huge string with the language I am using around JSON around HTML which may contain scripts, etc, etc. And since I am getting them from the output of another system, I do not want to manipulate them to fit my editor.

I managed to get it to a somewhat bearable level except that the vim limitation breaks syntax highlight for everything past those long lines. I assume this about vim saving resources, but I really want syntax highlight when working on those files.

Answer (score 24):

Use `:set synmaxcol=0` to remove the limit or choose any large value.

Warning: This setting may add a significant redraw delay.

> [Vim documentation: options - synmaxcol](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'synmaxcol')
>
> ```
> 'synmaxcol' 'smc' number  (default 3000)
>
> Notes: local to buffer, not in vi
> ```
>
> Maximum column in which to search for syntax items.  In long lines the
>   text after this column is not highlighted and following lines may not
>   be highlighted correctly, because the syntax state is cleared. This
>   helps to avoid very slow redrawing for an XML file that is one long
>   line.
>
> Set to zero to remove the limit.

Comment: Afterwards, you may have to `:syntax sync fromstart` to highlight existing text.